ROS Bridge docker broadcast topics outside of localhost
I am using the ros_bridge repository in a Docker container. Everything works on my local computer (computer #1) but once I want the published topics to be read over an ethernet interface to another computer (computer #2), it doesn't work. However, if I connect both computer #1 and computer #2 to the same Wi-Fi network, it works.
How do I tell ROS2 multicast to prioritize broadcasting the topics through an ethernet interface? I know I can turn off all network interfaces but the one I want ROS2 to multicast to, but I need computer #1 to be connected to the network for other reasons (like ssh).
Do you think the issue lies with the ros_bridge being inside a Docker? Is there a setting in Docker other than network_mode = host?
